How can I load non-related laravel model as relationship?
I have a User and Lesson models. these models are not related to each other.
users table: id, username, password, is_active
lessons table: id, title
// User
class User extends Model
{
    // code 
}

// Lesson
class Lesson extends Model
{
    public function users()
    {
        // I need to return all users here where is_active=true as RELATIONSHIP
        // return User::where('is_active', true);
    }
}

In the Lesson model I want to have a relationship to load users where (is_active, true)
So I can list all users where is_active = true
Thanks

"I want to have a relationship to load users where (is_active, true) So I can list all users where is_active = true" - what you are describing is not a relation. A relation between Lessons and Users would be a list of users who are following this lesson, or the inverse a list of lessons a user is following. Check Laravel docs for a many to many relation example

Thanks for answering, I know there is no relationship. But I still need it to act like a relationship to use it with filament relationship manager.

well you can't create a relationship out of nothing

thanks for trying to help
the list of users is like candidates to have a relationship

Since there's no actual foreign key relationship between Lesson and User, you need to create a custom method instead of a standard Eloquent relationship:
class Lesson extends Model
{
  public function activeUsers()
  {
    return User::where('is_active', true)->get();
  }
}


Why It's Not Recommended:

Lack of Integrity: Since there's no real foreign key relationship, you lose referential integrity. Laravel's built-in relationship methods like hasMany, belongsTo, etc., won't function as intended.
Limited Query Builder Features: Standard relationships in Laravel provide you with powerful features like eager loading (with), query constraints on related models, and lazy loading. A custom method like activeUsers doesn't integrate with these features.
Maintainability: This approach could lead to confusion for others (or even yourself in the future) who might expect a traditional relationship when they see a method named activeUsers. They might assume it's a standard relationship method, which it is not.

Recommended Approach

Use a Scope or Repository: If the relationship is purely logical and you need to filter users based on a condition like is_active, consider using a query scope in the User model or a repository pattern to handle this logic instead of placing it in the Lesson model.
Example:
class User extends Model
{
   public function scopeActive($query)
   {
       return $query->where('is_active', true);
   }
}

Then, in your controller or service, you can do:
$activeUsers = User::active()->get();


Thanks for your answer. The problem is I need it to return a relationship to use it with filament relationship manager.

It is possible, though a bit hacky and definetly not something i'd recommend doing.
You could create a static column on both lessons and users table, a field that always has the same value, "1" for example.
users.static_user_column = 1
lessons.static_lessons_column = 1

Then you could use that field as a relation column:

public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\User::class, 'static_user_column', 'static_lesson_column')
        ->where('is_active', true);
}

If is_active is an int then you could also substitute the user static column with is_active to filter them in the relation, but this could lead to side effects.

All the other answers are spot on. This should NOT be done in the first place.
If you are still insist on setting up that relationship. You can use the setRelation method:
$lesson = Lesson::find(1);

$users = User::where('is_active', true)->get();

$lesson->setRelation('users', $users);

// Then you can access users just like a relationship of that lesson.

$lesson->users;

You can read the Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Concerns\HasRelationships for more info.

Thanks a lot, How can implement your solution in the model level, because I need the relation to be in the model inorder to use it with filament relation manager
